# Why is there only circumferential treading on the nose wheel?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing-gear, braking

The pilot uses the nose wheel for steering on the ground, still all the tires on the aircraft use the same treading. Why are there no treads perpendicular to the rotation direction?

I know that most of the wheels on an aircraft are there just for the ride since there is no propulsion system acting on the wheels like with a car but the nose wheel has a similar task as the front wheels of lets say a lorry.

Comment: I believe the answer primarily has to do with allowing a channel for water dispersion to mitigate the chance of hydroplaning. That is, the water is thereby allowed to move into the channel and forward and aft, instead of forming a "wedge" under the tire and inducing hydroplaning. The concept is very similar to the corresponding grooving in many runways.

Comment: Actually, there is a propulsion system acting on the wheels: Brakes

Comment: @sweber: If brakes are propulsive devices... could they be used to increase perpetual motion efficiency?